# Different PDA design processes -- both valid?

Tags: automata, context-free, pushdown-automata

This video shows how to design PDA from a CFG:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZImtQBMSW_Y

Basically, we always have 4 basic states, and one of them is a "hub" for loops that implement separate rules like so ("q loop" state in the pic):

[image]

The author of the vid claims that any CFG can be converted into PDA using this basic structure.

Yet, I find PDAs that look very different.
E.g., this one:

[image]

My question: Is the single-hub method not always applicable? What are the general guidelines for when to use it and when not to use it?

If you could also explain how the PDA from the second image works step-by-step verbally, I would appreciate it.

Comment: The first PDA you presented is the automaton produced by following a general procedure of converting a CFG to PDA. To understand how it works you must at least know how derivation works. You use this generic procedure once you have CFG and you want to produce a (nondeterministic) PDA. AFAIK, you can always use this procedure to produce an NPDA but you must construct a CFG first. The second PDA you gave is constructed directly from the definition of the language without constructing first a CFG.

Comment: You can always produce the CFG from the PDA, and then convert it back to a PDA using the single hub method. So its always applicable, but not very intuitive if you dont already know the grammer.

Comment: But if I _do_ know the grammar, then can I _always_ use the "single-hub" method? Or are there cases when it's not recommended (or downright impossible)?